# Riverpod : Alternate way of overriding initState inside ConsumerWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

What is the solution of initializing things inside consumerWidget as because the initState method is not overridable here?

Answer (score 45):

**Riverpod v2.3.6**

You can use [ConsumerStatefulWidget](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerStatefulWidget-class.html) and [ConsumerState](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerState-class.html)

```
final helloWorldProvider = Provider((_) => 'Hello world');

class RiverpodExample extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RiverpodExample({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<RiverpodExample> createState() => _RiverpodExampleState();
}

class _RiverpodExampleState extends ConsumerState<RiverpodExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final value = ref.read(helloWorldProvider);
    print(value); // Hello world
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = ref.watch(helloWorldProvider);

    return Text(value); // Hello world
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, but its completely overlooking the power of Riverpod / ConsumerWidget

Comment: I don’t think any other way as of now @towhid

Comment: @VinothVino it seems ConsumerStateMixin is no longer available on flutter_riverpod 1.0.0

Comment: Riverpod 2.0 doesn't allow this anymore

Comment: Great example just what I was looking for. And @parkorian this does work in Riverpod 2.3 .

Comment: Important part of this answer to note is there is `read` in `initState` and `watch` in `build`. `Watch` doesn't work in `initState`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not totally sure how to answer your question as I have not worked with ConsumerWidget. I'd presume the idea is to keep most of your state in providers.

However, I would like to recommend using [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) alongside [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) (same [developer](https://github.com/rrousselGit)).

This makes keeping state local to the widget simple and also provides easy access to providers.

For example:

```dart
class Example extends HookWidget {
  const Example({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final test = useProvider(Test.provider());

    final controller = useTextEditingController();
    final loading = useState(false);
    final buttonText = useState('Change me!');

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(controller: controller),
        if (!loading) RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            loading.value = true;
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            buttonText.value = controller.text;
            loading.value = false;
          }
          child: Text(buttonText.value),
        ),
        if (loading) const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        // Do something with providers, etc.
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Just a quick example, but there are plenty of resources ([flutter_hooks](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks#flutter-hooks), [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/documentation/hooks_riverpod/latest/hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod-library.html)) to help you along. Also, check out [examples from the developer](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/tree/master/examples) on riverpod hooks usage.

Comment: After writing my code guided by your answer, I can conclude that this is the correct way to implement flutter_hooks with hook_riverpod and set variables at widget start up (and it's in the documentation). It's 'cause the initial values don't overwrite what you could set or update in the returned widget even though you rebuild it, so it's exactly like using initState.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but with the upcoming 1.0.0 of Riverpod you will be able to use https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/1.0.0-dev.2/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerStatefulWidget-class.html and https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/1.0.0-dev.2/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerState-class.html, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: @wujek, the accepted answer by Vinoth did the trick for me. Try to follow it and see if you can come right even without the links. I think they are still updating the docs.

Comment: What's funny is that his links are just as broken as are mine, but at least he has inline code ;)